# Get ranges of an ordered set of rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table.

`Seq  key
 1    A
 2    A
 3    A
 4    A
 5    B
 6    C
 7    C
 8    C
 9    C
 10   A
 11   A`

I want to query this and return a range of the key in order.

`key  strt  end
 A    1     4
 B    5     5
 C    6     9
 A    10    11`

I tried doing a min and max grouped by key but this does not consider the last A.

`select key, min(seq), max(seq) 
  from tblname
  group by key
  order by min(seq)`

I also tried to add another column just to uniquely identify the second set of A but i don't really want to add another column.
Note Seq here is unique and in an ordered sequence.

Is there a way to do this with only SQL? No procedures. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  key_,
  min(seq),
  max(seq)
from (
  select
    key_,
    seq,
    sum(case when key_ = l then 0 else 1 end) over (order by seq) s
  from (
    select 
      key_,
      seq,
      lag(key_) over (order by seq) l
    from
      tq84_  /* Insert table name here */
  )
)
group by
  key_,
  s
order by
  min(seq);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select key,
       seq,
       (select max(seq) from ts t2
        where seq >= t1.seq
          and not exists (select 1 from ts
                          where seq between t1.seq and t2.seq
                            and key <> t1.key))
from ts t1 where not exists (select 1 from ts
                             where key = t1.key
                               and seq = t1.seq - 1);
```

Executes as:

```
SQL>create table ts (seq int, key char(1));
SQL>insert into ts values (1,'A');
SQL>insert into ts values (2,'A');
SQL>insert into ts values (3,'A');
SQL>insert into ts values (4,'A');
SQL>insert into ts values (5,'B');
SQL>insert into ts values (6,'C');
SQL>insert into ts values (7,'C');
SQL>insert into ts values (8,'C');
SQL>insert into ts values (9,'C');
SQL>insert into ts values (10,'A');
SQL>insert into ts values (11,'A');
SQL>select key,
SQL&       seq,
SQL&       (select max(seq) from ts t2
SQL&        where seq >= t1.seq
SQL&          and not exists (select 1 from ts
SQL&                          where seq between t1.seq and t2.seq
SQL&                            and key <> t1.key))
SQL&from ts t1 where not exists (select 1 from ts
SQL&                             where key = t1.key
SQL&                               and seq = t1.seq - 1);

key            seq
===            ===
A                1           4
B                5           5
C                6           9
A               10          11

4 rows found
```

Comment: Wow thanks this work. let me play around with it with different scenarios